Customizing the error page based on the status instead of Tomcat default page with springboot
Not able to redirect the error in the custom page.
Configuration:
server:
  error:
    whitelabel:
      enabled: false
    path: /error

spring:
  web:
    resources:
      add-mappings: false

@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomErrorController implements ErrorController {
  private static final String PATH = "/error";

  @RequestMapping("/error")
  public String handleError(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Object status = request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE);

    if (status != null) {
      Integer statusCode = Integer.valueOf(status.toString());

      if (statusCode == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value()) {
        return "error-404";
      } else if (statusCode == HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value()) {
        return "error-500";
      }
    }
    return "error";
  }
}


what does "not able to" mean? have you tried debugging it? does your method get called when you open localhost:8080/error in your browser?

yes its being called.

if it is being called then all you are missing is the actual html pages (error.html, error-404 etc) being found. Try putting them into resources/templates

You don't need any of this. DItch your controller and just add an 404.html in your src/main/resources/templates/error. Which works for ranges as well by adding a 4xx.html or 5xx.html etc. This is for Thymeleaf, same works for other view technologies as well.
You can also put them in src/main/resources/public/error and as static html.
This is build into Spring Boot (which you would have found if you read the documentation)

I tried this way also but didnt work.

If this doesn't work you have some misconfiguration in your application. Probably something that disables auto-configuration like and @EnableWebMvc or the likes.

your annotations are wrong, it should be @Controller, not @RestController - because you resolving a page, not returning a resource

Yes i tried by using @Controller only but didnt work.

again, what does not work mean? Which response code are you getting? if 404 then maybe you just didn't put the error.html in the correct place? Where did you place it? What do the logs say?

Its responsing the bydefault tomcat error page instead of the customize page.
I put my error.html in resources folder

Error log:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target [/auth/api/reserve_action?vehicleId=3&reservationStatus=DELETED ]. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
